# Create pdf and png simultaneously

Tags: r

Is there any way in R to create a png and a pdf simultaneously without having to run the same code twice? I'd like both a raster and vector version of some figures to be produced without having to do an external conversion and without rerunning the code if possible. `dev.copy2pdf` sounds like what I need, but it seems that it only works from interactive devices.

Here's an example of what I'm doing:

```
pdf("temp.pdf")
plot(1:10)
#more drawing here
dev.off()

png("temp.png")
plot(1:10)
#more drawing here
dev.off()
```

Which I'd like to shorten to:

```
start()
plot(1:10)
#more drawing here
saveToPDF()
saveToPNG()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save a plot as PNG and PDF only by one call to the plot function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26232103/save-a-plot-as-png-and-pdf-only-by-one-call-to-the-plot-function-in-r)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an existing function `dev.copy2pdf()`, which does just what it says it will. There is also a function `dev.print()` which *looks like* it would  make copying to a `"*.png"` file easy, but is in my experience pretty hinky.

The following two  functions work well and have the added advantages of being uniformly named, and of taking all of their  arguments in the same order as the familiar and related `pdf()` and `png()` functions:

```
saveToPDF <- function(...) {
    d = dev.copy(pdf,...)
    dev.off(d)
}

saveToPNG <- function(...) {
    d = dev.copy(png,...)
    dev.off(d)
}

## Try them out
plot(rnorm(99),  col="red")
saveToPDF("my.pdf", height=4,width=7)
saveToPNG("my.png", height=600, width=400)
```

Comment: yes, but how do I do this without creating/updating the current interactive graphics device? for example, say you're doing `rnorm(99999)`, you don't want to have to wait for the current graphics device to update

Comment: @Noah. I'm not sure I follow you. What don't you like about the these functions' behavior when you run the code in your question's final code block?

Comment: With substantial numbers of data points (millions), it takes a lot longer to do the plot to screen, then save to png and pdf; is there any way to avoid using the interactive graphics device (that is, don't plot to screen)?

Comment: @Noah --  I see. That's enough of a different question that you should maybe write a second one. If I were trying to do that, I'd write functions that take an expression object `expr` as their first argument, then sandwich a call to `eval(expr)` between lines that open and close the respective devices. You would then wrap your plotting code in an expression object, and pass it into the functions.