# The dilemma of plot saving formats - R/base plots

Tags: r, plot, format

In my research work, when papers are to be communicated, the format could be either LaTeX or DOC/DOCX. This sends me into a dilemma.

I have generated PDFs (they can be easily included into a latex file) for certain plots using the base plot method. However, I would also like to have the PNG versions of the same plots (since MS Word does not accepts PDFs), and no, I do not want to rewrite codes! Further, the `convert` utility of `ImageMagick` is also not a preferable option, as there is a severe degradation in terms of resolution when one executes `convert myFile.pdf myFile.png`

What is the best way? Can we save a plot into a variable and then regenerate the plot to a png / jpg / tiff file?

Comment: Maybe this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26232103/save-a-plot-as-png-and-pdf-only-by-one-call-to-the-plot-function-in-r/26233113#26233113 can help you. It says how to produce both pdf and png files out of an R plot.

Comment: Actually, MacOS version of MS Word does work with PDFs.

Answer (score 0):

Save to EPS format ([see HowTo here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142842/export-a-graph-to-eps-file-with-r)). It is a vector format, and it should be recognizable by MS Word (you will need to import it as a picture) as well as LaTeX.